# ссылка на свойство внутри объекта javascript

Tags: javascript, объекты

Доброго времени. 
Есть такой вот объект.

```
  {
    location: {
      x: getRandomNum(300, 900),
      y: getRandomNum(100, 500)
    },
    offer: {
      title: getRandom(offerTitles),
      address: location.x, location.y,
      ....
      ....
    }
  }
```

Точнее есть массив, состоящий из таких вот объектов. address должна быть строкой со значениями координат. Как я могу получить доступ к location.x, location.y, чтобы прописать свойство offer.address? Сложность в том, что для каждого нового объекта - в location генерируется рандомное значение по-новому.

Comment: Откуда появляются эти объекты? Это json? Это литералы объектов в коде?

Comment: видимо в начале в какую-то отдельную переменную всё генерировать, а потом уже вставлять в объект

Comment: @Igor, не дубликат, если объекты получаются например из json

Comment: @Grundy принцип тот же - привязать подобъекты друг к другу дополнительным кодом

Answer (score 0):

Замените поля `offer`, `address` функциями

```js
function getRandomNum(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var obj = {
  location: {
    x: getRandomNum(300, 900),
    y: getRandomNum(100, 500)
  },
  offer: function() {
    var obj = this;
    return {
      title: 'Title',
      address: function() {
        return obj.location.x + ', ' + obj.location.y;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj.offer().address());
```

Comment: Ну и за что минус?